# Linked Server from On-Premise to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, linked-server, sql-server-2019

I am using:
SSMS-18.4
SQL Server-SQL 2019 CU3
Windows 10

I was able to create a linked server successfully from on-premise SQL 2017 to the Azure SQL database without exposing my password.

```
--Read the password from text file 
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @password = BulkColumn
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Azure SQL Database - Where is my  SQL Agent\password.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x   

--Drop and create linked server
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE name = N'AzureDB_adventureworks')
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'AzureDB_adventureworks', @droplogins='droplogins';
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
 @server = N'AzureDB_adventureworks', 
 @srvproduct=N'',
 @provider=N'SQLNCLI',
 @datasrc=N'ugdemotargetserver.database.windows.net',
 @catalog=N'adventureworks';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
 @rmtsrvname=N'AzureDB_adventureworks',
 @useself=N'False',
 @rmtuser=N'taiob',@rmtpassword=@password;
GO
```

But the password is not getting the correct value.  I am getting a login failure.

Some of the error message:

```
Login failed for user 'taiob'. 
(.Net SqlClient Data Provider) Server
Name: .\SQL2019 
Error Number: 18456 
Severity: 14 
State: 1 
Line Number: 1
```

I confirmed that it is reading the correct password from the file by running the following code:

```
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @password = BulkColumn
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Azure SQL Database - Where is my  SQL Agent\password.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x   
SELECT @password
```

I am using the same file in other places using PowerShell without any issues.

```
#Replace with password file location
$password = Get-Content "C:\Azure SQL Database - Where is my  SQL Agent\password.txt"
```

If I hardcode the password it works fine.  If I print the variable I can see the value is correct. It is not a firewall issue as I can directly connect from the same SSMS that I am running the code from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you create the text file, it can be in all sorts of formats.  Unicode or ANSI. With or without a Byte order Mark.  With or without trailing whitespace and line feeds, either posix or Windows style.

JSON is simpler that way.

For instance if you run cmd.exe

```
c:\>echo CowboYs4EVR! > password.txt
```

and then dump the bulk column

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\password.txt', SINGLE_blob) AS x
```

You'll see

```
0x436F77626F79733445565221200D0A
```

An ANSI tring with a trailing space and trailing CRLF, which you'll need to trim, like this:

```
set @password = trim(replace(replace(@password, char(13),''),char(10),''))
```

If you write the file from PowerShell it's likely to be unicode, etc.

But if you store the password in a json file instead, SQL Server will do the file format parsing for you.

eg something as simple as:

```
C:\temp>echo ["CowboYs4EVR!"] > password.json
```

and

```
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @password = json_value(BulkColumn, '$[0]')
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\password.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just reproduced your scenario and in my environment, it works. The only issue I could think of might be the reading of the text file. Could you maybe:

- try changing from SINGLE_BLOB to SINGLE_CLOB to ensure that it is read as a varchar(max) and not a varbinary?
- make sure that there are no whitespaces in your password string?
- try setting the password directly to the variable @password like this

```sql
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @password = '....'
```

hth

Comment: SINGLE_CLOB does not solve my problem. Checked for no whitespace. The direct setting works but I do not want that.